# Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected token "operator" of value ">"

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

Im developing my wordpress theme in a docker environment using timber / twig for my templating.

When i hosted my theme on a testwebsite i got the following 'fatal error'!

`<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught Twig_Error_Syntax: Unexpected token "operator" of value ">". in blabla/templates/single.twig:32`

Talking about the following code:

```
<p>
<strong>Tags:</strong> {{ post.tags|map(t => t.name)|join(', ') }}
</p>
```

I know I can rewrite the code and it will work without using the |map filter but thats not the point here ;-)

Comment: Which twig version are you using

Answer (score 1):

Stuck with the same problem. Somehow WP does not show me that update for timber plugin is available. Seems like timber team reverted plugin version and i didn't get the update(some problems with WPML compatibility).
Manually uploaded plugin v 1.9.5 (minimum required to understand arrow functions)

Answer (score 0):

So this is what i found out..

By using the Timber plugin i have no saying in what twig version i get. So i deactivated my current timber plugin, downloaded it again and checked what i got..

Turned out it included an older version on twig. :(

Updated the twig version in my local env. Uploaded that. And now it works :(

Answer (score 0):

Timber in WP repo has older version of Twig and always will. If you want to have the lates you should use Composer.
https://timber.github.io/docs/v2/installation/

Btw if you want to know Twig version try this

```
{{ constant('Twig_Environment::VERSION') }}
```